# Why CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity always gives MainActivity for any other Page in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have installed the [CurrentActivityPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin) in my Xamarin.Form's Android project to gain access of the top current activity.

I have `DashboardPage.xaml` & from this, I am navigating to another page `MyProfilePage.xaml`. At this level, If I try to get the current activity using `CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity`, it still gives me `MainActivity` only. Is there any way to know which Activity is associated with `MyProfilePage.xaml`?

Even, on Android's PageRenderer, it gives me `MainActivity` as Context, regardless of any page I navigate through.

Is this how Xamarin.Forms behaves with Page's underlying activity?

Please refer to the Android's PageRenderer screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how Xamarin works. All the navigations are done within a single Activity, MainActivity.

Comment: I do not think an activity changes when you have custom renderers it is called by MainActivity context only

Comment: @Bruno : Thanks. Does this mean that all ContentPages I push, are pushed as Fragments inside a single MainActivity? And, I did not understand your second sentence. sorry about that.

Comment: @MilanG Yes, all contentpages are pushed inside fragments always in the mainactivity, there's always just one activity in the Xamarin.Forms lifecycle. What I was trying to explain is that, sometimes, you can launch another activity from your Xamarin.Forms solution